# Gnumeric doesn't recognize numbers

Tags: spreadsheet, gnumeric

I am trying to do some basic calculations (mostly finding the median of a range of values) using gnumeric. Unfortunately, this is giving me a hard time. Consider the following data:

```
0.04 0.04 0 0 0.08
0.07 0.03 0 0.01 0.11
0.05 0.04 0 0 0.09
0.06 0.03 0 0.01 0.1
0.05 0.04 0 0 0.09
0.07 0.03 0 0.01 0.11
0.06 0.03 0 0 0.09
0.07 0.03 0 0.01 0.11
0.05 0.04 0 0 0.09
0.06 0.03 0 0 0.09
```

When I try to calculate the median using a range by issuing `=median(A1:A10)`, gnumerics result is #NUMBER, which I don't understand. The result is the same when using the syntax `=median(A1;A2;A3;..)`. If I try to compute the sum by using `=sum(A1:A10)`, the result is 0. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to format the columns in a specific way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this mistery is simple: gnumeric here uses `,` as the decimal separator, not `.`. In gnumeric, the decimal separator is set by the locale. If you want to use another decimal separator, simply use gnumeric with another locale, e.g. use `LC_NUMERIC=C`.